# Change a file to a list to a dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I am trying to write a code that takes the text from a novel and converts it to a dictionary where the keys are each unique word and the values are the number of occurrences of the word in the text.
For example it could look like: {'the': 25, 'girl': 59...etc}

I have been trying to make the text first into a list and then use the Counter function to make a dictionary of all the words:

```
    source = open('novel.html', 'r', encoding = "UTF-8")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
    #make a list of all the words in file, get rid of words that aren't content
    mylist = []
    mylist.append(soup.find_all('p'))
    newlist = filter(None, mylist)
    cnt = collections.Counter()
    for line in newlist:
         try:
           if line is not None:        
               words = line.split(" ")
               for word in line:
                cnt[word] += 1
         except:
           pass
    print(cnt)
```

This code doesn't work because of an error with "NoneType" or it just prints an empty list.  I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do what I'm trying to do or how I can fix this code so it won't have this error.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `filter(None, mylist)`?

Comment: Can you show what a snippet of what `mylist` looks like after this line: `mylist.append(soup.find_all('p'))`?

Answer (score 1):

For the counter just do a

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter(mylist)
```

Are you sure your list is getting items to begin with? After what step are you getting an empty list?

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('novel.html', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as source:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

cnt = collections.Counter()
for tag in soup.find_all('p'):
    for word in tag.string.split():
        word = ''.join(ch for ch in word.lower() if ch.isalnum())
        if word != '':
            cnt[word] += 1

print(cnt)
```

`with` statement is simply a safer way to open the file

`soup.find_all` returns a list of `Tag`'s

`tag.string.split()` gets all the words (separated by spaces) from the `Tag`

`word = ''.join(ch for ch in word.lower() if ch.isalnum())` removes punctuation and convertes to lowercase so that `'Hello'` and `'hello!'` count as the same word

Answer (score 0):

Once you've converted your page to a list, try something like this out:

```
#create dictionary and fake list

d = {}
x = ["hi", "hi", "hello", "hey", "hi", "hello", "hey", "hi"]

#count the times a unique word occurs and add that pair to your dictionary

for word in set(x):
    count = x.count(word)
    d[word] = count
```

Output:

```
{'hello': 2, 'hey': 2, 'hi': 4}
```

Comment: I would change `for word in x:` to `for word in set(x):` so that you don't keep recounting words. Here you are counting elements more than once.